# Grails: how to re initialize AJAX content in twitter bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I have a modal. Its default content is loaded into it by the database for every iteration of tableInstance. Then i have a `remoteLink` button which updates the `tableShown` when it is clicked.

Problem is that if you have clicked the `remoteLink` button and you close the modal, the content of `remoteLink` is still there when the modal is shown. It is supposed to be the default content that is loaded from the database.

How do you re initialize the content of a modal? I tried it with

```
<g:javascript>
    $("#show_${t.id}").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
         $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
    });
</g:javascript>
```

but it still shows the content of

```
<g:remoteLink id="${t.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="editTable" update="tableShown_${t.id}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Edit
    </button>
</g:remoteLink>
```

Here is my full code snippet

```
<g:each in="${tableInstanceList.sort{a,b-> a.tableNumber.compareTo(b.tableNumber)}}" var="t">

    <a href="#show_${t.id}" data-toggle="modal" class="table" >Table ${t.tableNumber?.encodeAsHTML()}</a>               

        <div class="modal fade" id="show_${t.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:43%;">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button style="margin:5px 7px 0px 0px; " type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>                                                       

                            <div id="tableShown_${t.id}">

                                <ol class="property-list">  
                                    <g:if test="${t?.tableNumber}">
                                        <li class="fieldcontain" style="margin-left:6px;">
                                            <span id="tableNumber-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.tableNumber.label" default="Table Number " /></span>
                                            <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="tableNumber-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="tableNumber"/></span>
                                        </li>
                                    </g:if>

                                    <g:if test="${t?.numberOfChairs}">
                                        <li class="fieldcontain">
                                            <span id="numberOfChairs-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.numberOfChairs.label" default="Number Of Chairs" /></span>
                                            <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="numberOfChairs-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="numberOfChairs"/></span>
                                        </li>
                                    </g:if>

                                    <g:if test="${t?.mergedWith}">
                                        <li class="fieldcontain">
                                            <span id="mergedWith-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.mergedWith.label" default="Merged With" /></span>
                                            <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="mergedWith-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="mergedWith"/></span>                                           
                                        </li>
                                    </g:if>

                                    <g:if test="${t?.status}">
                                        <li class="fieldcontain">
                                            <span id="status-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.status.label" default="Status" /></span>
                                            <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="status-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="status"/></span>                                                   
                                        </li>
                                    </g:if>

                                    <g:if test="${t?.orderSlip}">
                                        <li class="fieldcontain">
                                            <span id="orderSlip-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.orderSlip.label" default="Order Slip" /></span>        
                                            <g:each in="${t.orderSlip}" var="o">
                                                <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="orderSlip-label">${o?.encodeAsHTML()}</span>
                                            </g:each>
                                        </li>
                                    </g:if>                                                                                 
                                </ol>

                                <g:form>
                                    <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${t.id}" />

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="_action_deleteTable" value="deleteTable">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Delete
                                    </button>                                               

                                    <g:remoteLink id="${t.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="editTable" update="tableShown_${t.id}">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Edit
                                        </button>
                                    </g:remoteLink> 

                                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                </g:form>

                            </div>              
                        </div>  
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->

            <g:javascript>
                $("#show_${t.id}").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
                });
            </g:javascript>                             
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is (I imagine) because the form submission overrides the remoteLink, so it's reloading the page which would reset your content, causing it to stay the same.  I'm not quite sure why you're using a form to begin with.  I don't have a high enough rep to comment to ask that, so I'll provide what I would do differently.

I would change this:

```
<g:form>
    <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${t.id}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="_action_deleteTable" value="deleteTable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Delete
    </button>                                               

    <g:remoteLink id="${t.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="editTable" update="tableShown_${t.id}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Edit
        </button>
    </g:remoteLink> 

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</g:form>
```

To this:

```
<g:link action="deleteTable" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="${t.id}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Delete
</g:link>

<g:remoteLink id="${t.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="editTable" update="tableShown_${t.id}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Edit
</g:remoteLink>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Unless there's a specific reason you're using a form, this should do exactly what you need.  Hope this helps!