# Grails: using include in a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails

How do you use the `<g:include>` in a javascript? Because i want it everytime when my modal shows to use this `<g:include id="${t.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="showTable"/>`

```
$("#show_${t.id}").on('show.bs.modal', function () {

});
```

UPDATE

Basically `<g:include id="${t.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="showTable"/>` will show this after the modal is shown

```
<ol class="property-list">  
                                <g:if test="${t?.tableNumber}">
                                    <li class="fieldcontain" style="margin-left:6px;">
                                        <span id="tableNumber-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.tableNumber.label" default="Table Number " /></span>
                                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="tableNumber-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="tableNumber"/></span>
                                    </li>
                                </g:if>

                                <g:if test="${t?.numberOfChairs}">
                                    <li class="fieldcontain">
                                        <span id="numberOfChairs-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.numberOfChairs.label" default="Number Of Chairs" /></span>
                                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="numberOfChairs-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="numberOfChairs"/></span>
                                    </li>
                                </g:if>

                                <g:if test="${t?.mergedWith}">
                                    <li class="fieldcontain">
                                        <span id="mergedWith-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.mergedWith.label" default="Merged With" /></span>
                                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="mergedWith-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="mergedWith"/></span>                                           
                                    </li>
                                </g:if>

                                <g:if test="${t?.status}">
                                    <li class="fieldcontain">
                                        <span id="status-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.status.label" default="Status" /></span>
                                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="status-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${t}" field="status"/></span>                                                   
                                    </li>
                                </g:if>

                                <g:if test="${t?.orderSlip}">
                                    <li class="fieldcontain">
                                        <span id="orderSlip-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="table.orderSlip.label" default="Order Slip" /></span>        
                                        <g:each in="${t.orderSlip}" var="o">
                                            <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="orderSlip-label">${o?.encodeAsHTML()}</span>
                                        </g:each>
                                    </li>
                                </g:if>                                                                                 
                            </ol>

                            <g:form>
                                <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${t.id}" />

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="_action_deleteTable" value="deleteTable">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Delete
                                </button>                                               

                                <g:remoteLink id="${t.id}" controller="superAdmin" action="editTable" update="tableShown_${t.id}">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> Edit
                                    </button>
                                </g:remoteLink> 

                                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                            </g:form>
```

here's a link to my other question [Grails: how to re initialize AJAX content in twitter bootstrap 3 modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468289/grails-how-to-re-initialize-ajax-content-in-twitter-bootstrap-3-modal). Its related to this because i dont know the correct workaround for the problem. There's an explanation on what the modal is supposed to show

Comment: what result you're expecting?

Comment: so, the problem that you have a visible DOM element after you close modal dialog?

Comment: the problem is that the previous visible DOM element is not shown after u update the modal with AJAX using `remoteLink`

Comment: but what html do you get at this situation?

Comment: So the content of `remoteLink` is shown when u close and reopen the modal. I tried destroying the modal. But i dont know how to re initialize it.

Comment: Seems that this is a local issue, and it's really hard to tell what's happening w/o debugging

Comment: I see. What if  i load the content everytime the modal is shown using ajax so it is reloaded everytime on `show.bs.modal`. How do you do that?